# Performance Comparison of Multiple Join and Multiple Subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I know that this type of questions are asked before, but I couldn't find one with my exact problem.
I'll try to give an exaggerated example.

Let's say that we want to find companies with at least one employee older than 40 and at least one customer younger than 20.

Query my colleague wrote for this problem is like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(c.NAME) FROM COMPANY c 
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE e ON c.COMPANY_ID = e.COMPANY_ID 
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER u ON c.COMPANY_ID = u.COMPANY_ID
WHERE e.AGE > 40 and u.AGE < 20
```

I'm new to databases. But looking at this query (like a time complexity problem) it will create an unnecessarily huge temporary table. It will have employeeAmount x customerAmount rows for each companies.

So, I re-wrote the query:

```
SELECT c.NAME FROM COMPANY c 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE e WHERE e.AGE > 40 AND c.COMPANY_ID = e.COMPANY_ID  )
  OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER u WHERE u.AGE < 20 AND c.COMPANY_ID = u.COMPANY_ID )
```

I do not know if this query will be worse since it will run 2 subqueries for each company.

I know that there can be better ways to write this. For example writing 2 different subqueries for 2 age conditions and then UNION'ing them may be better. But I really want to learn if there is something wrong with one of / both of two queries.

Note: You can increase the join/subquery amount. For example, "we want to find companies with at least one employee older than 40 and at least one customer younger than 20 **and at least one order bigger than 1000$**"

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `AND` to combine the two `EXISTS` to answer your problem correctly?

Answer (score 2):

The `exists` version should have much better performance in general, especially if you have indexes on `company_id` in each of the subtables.

Why?  The `JOIN` version creates an intermediate result with all customers over 40 and all employees under 20.  That could be quite large if these groups are large for a particular company.  Then, the query does additional work to remove duplicates.

There might be some edge cases where the first version has fine performance.  I would expect this, for instance, if either of the groups were empty -- no employees ever under 20 or no customers ever over 40.  Then the intermediate result set is empty and removing duplicates is not necessary.  For the general case, though, I recommend `exists`.

Answer (score 2):

To know what really happens in *your* current environment, with *your* database settings and with *your* data you need to compare *real* execution plans (not just EXPLAIN PLAN which gives only the estimated plan). Only real execution plan can give detailed resources used by the query like CPU and IO in addition to detailed steps used by Oracle (full table scan, joins, etc.).

Try:

```
ALTER SESSION STATISTICS_LEVEL=ALL;

<your query>

SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display(NULL, NULL, format=>'allstats last'));
```

Do not assume, just test.